# How can I connect a function to VS Code Webview?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webview, vscode-extensions

I have a function that fetches and parses through some data in a file of my project directory, and sends the command to the CLI using activeTerminal.sendText(). On the webview, I want to have a "install" button, that will send "npm install somePlugin" to the CLI.

However, the functionality that fetches and parses is define in a js file, and 'webview.html' will not have access to the function because webviews are isolated environments.

My first question is how can I make the webview have access to the functionality? I have tried adding a script tag (with enableScript) in the 'webview.html', and define the functionality using template literal, but it does not work.

Even if this issue is solved, the functionality involves sending commands to the terminal in the 'webview.html' with activeTerminal.sendText(), which I think the webview would not interpret.

How can I solve these issues? Currently, the install button on webview does nothing when clicked.

```
The code is below:
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import PluginData from '../models/NpmData';
import { PluginPkg } from '../utils/Interfaces';
import Utilities from './Utilities';

export default class WebViews {
  static async openWebView(npmPackage: PluginPkg) {
    const { links, name, version, description } = npmPackage;
    const readMe = await PluginData.mdToHtml(links.repository, links.homepage);

    // turn npm package name from snake-case to standard capitalized title
    const title = name
      .replace(/-/g, ' ')
      .replace(/^\w?|\s\w?/g, (match: string) => match.toUpperCase());

    // createWebviewPanel takes in the type of the webview panel & Title of the panel & showOptions
    const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
      'plugin',
      `Gatsby Plugin: ${title}`,
      vscode.ViewColumn.One,
      {
        enableScripts: true
      }
    );

    // create a header for each npm package and display README underneath header
    // currently #install-btn does not work
    // const gatsbycli = new GatsbyCli();
    let installCmnd;

    async function installPlugin(npmName: string, npmLinks: any): Promise<void> {
      const activeTerminal = Utilities.getActiveTerminal();
      const rootPath = Utilities.getRootPath();
      // gets to npmPackage
      // const { name, links } = npmPackage
      // plugin.command.arguments[0];

      if (npmLinks) {
        console.log('npmlinks!');
        installCmnd =
          (await PluginData.getNpmInstall(npmLinks.repository, npmLinks.homepage)) ||
          `npm install ${npmName}`;
  
        if (rootPath) {
          activeTerminal.sendText(`cd && cd ${rootPath}`);
          activeTerminal.sendText(installCmnd);
          activeTerminal.show(true);
        } else {
          activeTerminal.sendText(installCmnd);
          activeTerminal.show(true);
        }
        // check for if "plugin" is a theme or actual plugin
        if (npmName.startsWith('gatsby-theme')) {
          vscode.window.showInformationMessage(
            'Refer to this theme\'s documentation regarding implementation. Simply click on the theme in the "Themes" section.',
            'OK'
          );
        } else {
          vscode.window.showInformationMessage(
            'Refer to this plugin\'s documentation regarding further configuration. Simply click on the plugin in the "Plugins" section.',
            'OK'
          );
        }
      }
    }
    panel.webview.postMessage('hi');
    panel.webview.html = `
    <style>
      .plugin-header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        background-color: var(--vscode-editor-background);
        width: 100vw;
      }

      #title-btn {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        align-text: center;
      }

      #install-btn {
        height: 1.5rem;
        margin: 1rem;
      }

      body {
        position: absolute;
        top: 9rem;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="plugin-header">
      <div id="title-btn">
        <h1 id="title">${title}</h1>
        <button id="install-btn" ***onclick="${installPlugin(name, links)}"***>Install</button>
      </div>
      <p>Version: ${version}</p>
      <p>${description}</p>
      
      <hr class="solid">
    </div>

    ${readMe}
    `;
```

Comment: read the webview page of the VSC doc and you can call an extension function from the webview. https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#passing-messages-from-a-webview-to-an-extension

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make install button work in VSCode extension Webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64395277/is-there-a-way-to-make-install-button-work-in-vscode-extension-webview)